# Why when I define the variable outside the loop, it doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I am working on leetcode question no.832. Could any one explain to me why when I define the temp inside the loop, the code gives me the correct output, while when I define it at the beginning of the function, it doesn't.

```
var flipAndInvertImage = function(image) {
    let temp = new Array(image.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++ ){
        //let temp = new Array(image.length);
        for (var j =0; j< image.length ; j++) {
            temp[j] = 1-image[i][image.length - j - 1];

        }
        image[i] = temp; 
    }
    return image; 
};

image = [[1,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,0,0]];
result = flipAndInvertImage(image);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Javascript assignment operator works by reference, not by value, so by defining it at the beginning, the three

```
image[i] = temp;
```

are actually assigning to `image[i]` the same array... you can check this by changing the value of one array at the end, and you will see that it changes in all of three:

```
var flipAndInvertImage = function(image) {
    let temp = new Array(image.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++ ){
        //let temp = new Array(image.length);
        for (var j =0; j< image.length ; j++) {
            temp[j] = 1-image[i][image.length - j - 1];

        }
        image[i] = temp; 
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(image)) // [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
    image[0][0]=9
    console.log(JSON.stringify(image)) // [[9,1,1],[9,1,1],[9,1,1]]
    return image; 
};

image = [[1,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,0,0]];
result = flipAndInvertImage(image);
console.log(result);
```

therefore `image[0]`, `image[1]`, `image[2]` "point" to the same array, because they contains a reference to the same array